# Extrapolate (and Interpolate) Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, interpolation, extrapolation

I have a pandas dataframe as below

[image]

(Year index is int64, Total_Population_Final is float.)

I want to create a linear interpolation (and extrapolation), but using pd.interpolate() I only seem to be able to create an interpolation between the two years (not extending it forward and backward in time).

Comment: try adding `limit_area ='outside'`

Comment: @Reza unfortunately that only forward fills the last value (not in a linear fashion, and keeps all else as NaN)

Comment: Don't post your data as images. Copy past it in question.

Answer (score 2):

Update: I have solved this (for anyone interested for future reference), using:

```
pd.interpolate(method="spline", order=1, limit_direction="both")
```

Comment: This seems to just backfill and forwardfill - it doesn't extrapolate the data using a linear regression.